# Problems with Ant Design, mountNode

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm developing at the time a concept for an own app and I'm using Ant Design. every time I'm trying to render there are the following errors:

**Failed to compile**

> ./src/App.js   Line 59:  'ReactDOM' is not defined   no-undef   Line
>   59:  'mountNode' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide your code or sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using ReactDOM but haven't imported it. Use `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` at the top for removing first error.

For second error:

You need to tell React where to mount your component.

You probably want to replace `mountNode` with `document.getElementById('help')` to refer to your `<div id="help"></div>` element.